# What are the consequences of presentation of an algebra by generators and relations?

Tags: ring-theory, representation-theory, modules, algebras

Let $A$ be a finite dimensional associative $K$-algebra, where  $K$ is a field.

I wonder how the presentation of $ A $ by generators and relations helps in the study of structure of the algebra itself? or are there any major consequences of this presentation?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, suppose $A$ is $2$-dimensional with basis $(e_1,e_2)$ and products $e_1\cdot e_1=e_2$, and all other products of basis elements zero. We see that $A$ is associative, commutative and a Jordan nilalgebra.

Comment: A presentation of such an algebra as the path algebra of a quiver with admissible relations is a very useful one if you want to study its representation theory - this is a huge subject, but the book "Elements of the Representation Theory of Associative Algebras" by Assem, Simson and Skowroński covers lots of it.

Comment: How much information the generators and relations give is really dependent on subject.  For example, as Matt mentioned, if (quotiented) path algebras are essentially associative algebras with 1-dimensional simple top presented in generators (arrows of the quiver) and relations, and where one can work with their homological algebra pretty much combinatorially.  On the other extreme, the Hecke algebras, universal eneveloping algebras of Lie algebras can also be defined by generators and relations, but their representations are way much harder to study compare to path algebras.